# preview @page rendering in browser window

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, pdfkit

So I have a rails app that produces a printable document. This document has several sections, each with a title, subsections with subtitles, and content areas. I would like to make sure that the sections are not broken up across pages:

---

*some content...*

## Section Title

### Section Subtitle

Section content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut laoreet lacus. Nulla consectetur non ligula et dapibus. Mauris tincidunt, libero at mollis maximus, dui risus ultricies diam, vehicula semper libero

--------- page break ----------

ex non tortor. Sed ac sollicitudin lacus, nec feugiat ipsum. Nulla congue arcu ut purus cursus, eget feugiat urna tincidunt. Mauris arcu tellus...

---

In other words, I want to make sure that, if I cannot have at least 3 lines of the content on the same page as the section title and subtitle, the entire section gets forced to the next page.

The current CSS specs include "page-break-after" and "orphan" controls. In theory I should be able to apply a "page-break-after: avoid" style to the title and subtitle, and an "orphan: 3" style to the content. However, apparently [NO browsers support this spec](http://caniuse.com/#search=page-break) (and I have confirmed this in FF & Chrome on Mac).

Is there any way to achieve this programatically? I could use JS/jquery to calculate/set the position of elements, but this seems very tricky and likely to not work given the variables involved.

Alternatively, is there any way to force the browser to render a page visually as it would if it were being printed out?

I should also add we're using PDFkit (wkhtmltopdf) to produce a PDF as the final product, so if there's any way those tools can be used to achieve the same end, or another gem or tool (other than Prawn) to achieve this, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `page-break-*` rules are generally supported with a *small* exception of not supporting exactly the ones you want `page-break-after` and `page-break-before`.

However, most browsers seems to support `page-break-inside` CSS rule. So, if you think about it, we can use it as a workaround. If you wrap your title and the next 3 paragraph in a single `div` with this property, then you get what you want.

```css
@media print {
  .no-print-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>some content...</p>

<div class="no-print-break">
  <h1>Section Title</h1>
  <h2>Section Subtitle</h2>
  <p>Section content lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut laoreet lacus. Nulla consectetur non ligula et dapibus. Mauris tincidunt, libero at mollis maximus, dui risus ultricies diam, vehicula semper libero.</p>
</div>
<p>Content that can move to another page</p>
```

Comment: Well, if it's the rule you NEED it's not exactly a SMALL exception ;-)I thought about that...

Comment: Yeap, that's what I meant and emphasized :) Did you try the `page-break-inside` workaround? Is it a viable option?

Comment: Well, if it's the rule you NEED it's not exactly a SMALL exception ;-)

I thought about your suggestion. But I would have to dynamically wrap the content in the div, splitting the content, which would be tricky, plus the last of the "orphan" lines likely wouldn't go all the way to the end, resulting in a break between the first three lines of the content and the remaining content.

If I could accurately calculate where the break would occur it might work, I'll give it a shot, but I suspect there will be so much variation among browsers it may be impossible.

Comment: Maybe if I: 1. Accurately recreate a div the width of page the user is going to be printing to (letter, A4, half-letter, legal, etc.), 2. Calculate where the breaks would be (based on the paper length), 3. Flow the content into the div, 4. Get the offset of each element, 5. Calculate padding needed to shift elements down to avoid breaks, and 6. Insert the padding elements.

Comment: I thought you only care about the content after your headers? No need to calculate, just wrap your header and first paragraph within the `div`. It is not "first 3 lines", but it's the best we can get.